# Change a paragraph with a button within a boostrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, paragraph

I have three buttons within a bootstrap carousel, i'd like to change a paragraph underneath those buttons based on the button i press say button 1,2,3.

button 1 "Hello and welcome to my website"

button 2 "Here is a very simple Carousel i hope you enjoy it"

button 3 "I'm trying to change this text"

If i press button 1 then that text will display,if i press button 2 the text will change to button 2 text.

here is my carousel

```
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-tv fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
                    <h4>Bootstrap 3</h4>
                    <p>Hello and welcome to my website</p>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
            </div><!-- end item -->

            <div class="item" id="slide2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Learning to code</h4>
                    <p>Here is a very simple Carousel i hope you enjoy it</p>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
            </div><!-- end item -->

            <div class="item" id="slide3">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>My Website</h4>
                    <p>I'm trying to change this text </p>
                </div><!-- end carousel-caption-->
            </div><!-- end item -->
        </div><!-- carousel-inner -->

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>

    </div><!-- end myCarousel -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of it is just with data attributes.

```
<a href="#" data-text-default="true" data-text-value="Hello My Name Is" data-target="#textTarget">Button 1</a><br />
<a href="#" data-text-value="Welcome to my site" data-target="#textTarget">Button 2</a><br />
<a href="#" data-text-value="I Currently Work At" data-target="#textTarget">Button 1</a><br />
<div id="textTarget">Original Text</div>
```

Then with a simple script you can automatically detect text changes throughout your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-text-default="true"]').

   $('body').on('click','[data-text-value]', function(event){
      if(!this.$) this.$ = $(this);

      if(typeof(this.t$) == "undefined") {
          var target = this.$.data('target');
          this.t$ = target ? $(this.$.data('target')) : false;
      }
      if(!this.t$) return;
      this.t$.html(this.$.data('text-value'));
   });
});
```

Then anywhere you want to do a dynamic block you can just add the attributes:

- **data-target**:  A jQuery Selector for the element you want to change.
- **data-text-value**:  The text you want to replace in the target element
- **data-text-default**:  Value should be true for any item you want to be the default text shown.

### *Updated*: Includes Default Text

Here is the Snippet to Demonstrate:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Add Default Texts
   $('[data-text-default="true"]').each(function(i,el){
       el.$ = $(el);
       el.t$ = $(el.$.data('target'));
       el.t$.html(el.$.data('text-value'));
     });
   //Add Event Handler
   $('body').on('click','[data-text-value]', function(event){
      if(!this.$) this.$ = $(this);
      
      if(typeof(this.t$) == "undefined") {
          var target = this.$.data('target');
          this.t$ = target ? $(this.$.data('target')) : false;
      }
      if(!this.t$) return;
      this.t$.html(this.$.data('text-value'));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-text-default="true" data-text-value="Hello My Name Is" data-target="#textTarget">Button 1</a><br />
<a href="#" data-text-value="Welcome to my site" data-target="#textTarget">Button 2</a><br />
<a href="#" data-text-value="I Currently Work At" data-target="#textTarget">Button 1</a><br />
<div data-text-value="DIV BLOCK WAS CLICKED" data-target="#textTarget">Div Block</div>
<div id="textTarget">Original Text</div>
```

Comment: thats great thank you for the reply,is there anyway of pre-filling the textTarget with one of the buttons data instead of displaying Original Text

Comment: Yes.  You can have a class defined it a days attribute that is searched for in the ready function which sets that value as default

Comment: im not great with javascript could you point me in the direction of where i could learn what you telling me to do thanks

Comment: thank you very much my first stop is a javascript course